# What's wrong with this program to check the whether or not a number is an Armstrong number?

Tags: c

I was making a program to check whether a given number is an Armstrong number or not, but it is not working correctly. I had used two print statements to check how much of my code is working but they are showing value of count and total as 0. I don't know what is going wrong here.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

 int main ()
 {
  //Program to check if a given number is Armstrong or not.
  int num, count, remain, total = 0;
  int onum = num;
  printf ("Enter a number:\n");
  scanf ("%d", &num);
  while (onum != 0)
    {
      onum = onum / 10;
      count++;
    }
  printf ("Value stored at count is %d\n", count);
  onum = num;
  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        remain = onum % 10;
        total += pow (remain, count);
        onum = onum / 10;
    }
  printf ("Value stored at Total is %d\n", total);
  if (num == total)
    {
        printf ("The entered number is an Armstrong\n");
    }
  else
    {
        printf ("The entered number is not an Armstrong\n");
    }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `onum` is assigned with `num`, which is uninitialized at that point.

Comment: Note: `int num, count, remain, total = 0;` is different from `int num = 0, count = 0, remain = 0, total = 0;`  This is one of many reasons why it is generally recommended to avoid declaring multiple variables on one line.

Comment: You should avoid using `pow()` with integer computations unless you `round()` the value.

Comment: You might want to include the definition of an Armstrong number somewhere

Answer (score 0):

```c
int onum = num;
```

is bad. Variables in C are not automatically updated after assignment. You should assign `num` to `onum` only after reading a value to `num`.

Also you have to initialize `count` before performing arithmetics with the value of the variable.

The part

```c
  int onum = num;
  printf ("Enter a number:\n");
  scanf ("%d", &num);
```

should be:

```
  int onum;
  printf ("Enter a number:\n");
  scanf ("%d", &num);
  onum = num;
  count = 0;
```

Also it is better to check the return value of `scanf()` to see if it successfully read what should be read:

```c
  int onum;
  printf ("Enter a number:\n");
  if (scanf ("%d", &num) != 1)
    {
      fputs("read error\n", stderr);
      return 1;
    }
  onum = num;
  count = 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

I figured out my mistake thank you all to help me.
The thing I did wrong was not initializing my variable with zero and

```
int onum = num;
```

I did this after getting the value of num first. I already knew it but somehow still did a mistake.
And, the last thing is rounding of the remainder before using it in the pow function.

```
round(re);
```

The correct code is given below.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

    int
    main ()
    {
      //Program to check if a given number is Armstrong or not.
      int num = 0, count = 0, remain = 0, total = 0;
      printf ("Enter a number:\n");
      scanf ("%d", &num);
      int onum = num;
      while (onum != 0)
        {
          onum = onum / 10;
          count++;
        }
      printf ("Value stored at count is %d\n", count);
      onum = num;
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            remain = onum % 10;
             int re = round(remain);
            total += pow (re, count);
            onum = onum / 10;
        }
      printf ("Value stored at Total is %d\n", total);
      if (num == total)
        {
            printf ("The entered number is an Armstrong\n");
        }
      else
        {
            printf ("The entered number is not an Armstrong\n");
        }
      return 0;
    }
```